# How to customize JForum?

Tags: java, jsp, forum

I am creating a site that needs a forum feature. While searching through the net of best third party forum for Java, I came across JForum. The connection to the database and initial test was pretty good. but my problem now is how could I be able to embed or customize it so I can place it in the site that I am making. Hope you could help me. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please, have you found a solution ? I am facing the exact same situation now

Answer (score 2):

The best way I think is to deploy JForum as an subdomen to your site, in that way you will be able to access it at the address: http://example.com/JForum/

Comment: This is not a subdomain - a subdomain would be something like http://jforum.example.com/.